# Gradle 8 and JFrog Artifactory

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I updated gradle 7.6.1 to version 8.0.2. But now an artifactory task is giving an error and I can't fix it.

error:

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':artifactoryPublish'.
>
> > Resolving dependency configuration 'archives' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'.   Instead, a resolvable
> > ('canBeResolved=true') dependency configuration that extends
> > 'archives' should be resolved.

my build.gradle.kt

```
plugins {
  `maven-publish`
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.10"
  id("org.jetbrains.qodana") version "0.1.12"
  id("com.jfrog.artifactory") version "4.31.8"
  id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.22.0"
  id("com.github.spotbugs") version "5.0.13"
}


artifactory {
    setContextUrl(artifactoryContextUrl)
    publish {
      repository {
        setRepoKey("Deploy")
        setUsername(artifactoryUser)
        setPassword(artifactoryPassword)
        setMavenCompatible(true)
      }
      defaults {
        setPublishPom(true)
        setPublishIvy(false)
        setPublishArtifacts(true)
        publications("ALL_PUBLICATIONS")
        publishConfigs("archives", "archives")
      }
    }
    resolve {
      repository {
        setRepoKey("Virtual")
        setUsername(artifactoryUser)
        setPassword(artifactoryPassword)
        setMaven(true)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior was deprecated in Gradle 7: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#deprecations_7

You must use a configuration that is resolvable and provided by either your project or a plugin you may be using such as the Java Library plugin. For example, that could be the `compileClasspath` configuration.

Comment: what's the best way to do this?  added the following line:
configurations.findByName("archives")?.isCanBeResolved = true
But I don't know if it's the best thing to do.

Comment: @RodrigoBatista - could you explain where to put the line you posted? We are currently having the same problem here...